# RequireJS does not cache all files like expected, it only caches part of it (see my htaccess file as well)

Tags: .htaccess, caching, requirejs

[image]

my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Activate mod_expires for this directory
ExpiresActive on
#HTML documents are good for a week from the time they were changed
ExpiresDefault M604800 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The response and request headers

[image]

This `max-age=0` is missing in the js files that actually get cached.

Someone understands what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out thanks to

https://superuser.com/questions/313131/how-do-i-stop-chrome-sending-cache-control-max-age-0-when-i-hit-enter

It is a chrome problem, when you actually press CTRL+R to refresh the page chrome will send some request headers with max-age=0 as well as when you hit enter into the url. Seems a bit random. But won't affect the normal user experience a lot.